# Removing element from link ID for jQuery tab script

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have a jQuery tab script that gets content from a PHP file defined by the link and parses it to a div element. The ID for each link is used to pull content from the correct file however type_ is needed in the link ID for the tabs to work which then doesn't pull content from the right place. How can I resolve this issue?

This is my current jQuery code:

```
function load(url){
    $.ajax({
        url:url,
        success:function(message){
            $("#content").html(message);
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("[id^=type_]").click(function(){
        type=$(this).attr("id");
        url=""+type+".php";
        $("[id^=type_]").removeClass("selected");
        $("#"+type).addClass("selected");
        load(url);
        return false;
    });
    $("#type_search").click();
});
```

This is my HTML code:

```
<ul> 
<li><a id="type_tab1" href="javascript:void(null);">Tab1</a></li> 
<li><a id="type_tab2" href="javascript:void(null);">Tab2</a></li> 
<li><a id="type_tab3" href="javascript:void(null);">Tab3</a></li> 
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description, I assume you mean the content is located at `tab1.php`, `tab2.php`, etc and the problem is with your `type_` prefix in the ID.

**Option #1 - Most like your code**

I don't think you need `type_` in the id.  Seems like you could accomplish the same thing with a `class='tab'` on each of your anchors like

```
<li><a id="tab1" class="tab" href="javascript:void(null);">Tab1</a></li>
```

and then do

```
$('.tab').click(function() {
    var tabId = $(this).attr("id");
    var url=""+tabId+".php";
    $('.tab').removeClass("selected");
    $('#' + tabId).addClass("selected");
    load(url);
    return false;
}
```

**Option #2 - Cleaner and makes more sense**

There's no reason to overload the ID attribute with the url of your content.  Try:

```
<li><a id="tab1" class="tab" href="/path/to/content/tab1.php">Tab1</a></li>
```

Normally, this would take you to the content, but you can prevent the default behavior by:

```
$('.tab').click(function(event) {

    // Prevent actually going to the content
    event.preventDefault();

    // Adjust tabs
    var $currentTab = $(this);        
    $('.tab').removeClass("selected");
    $currentTab.addClass("selected");

    // Load content from the href attribute of the tab          
    load($currentTab.attr("href"));

    return false;
}
```

**Option #3 - This is already a JQuery Extension**

Have you considered using JQuery UI Tabs?  http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/  I've found the demo site to be a bit wonky sometimes, but JQuery UI is very popular, stable, and flexible.  There is an option to load content via AJAX.